# How to check if I reached a X limit in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, debian

Is there a way to check if I reached a limit/kernel limit of any kind of buffer in Linux?

Like one command that tell you :

```
openfile limit reached
max net connection reached
net buffer full
inodes full
memory buffer full
```

All the other weird buffers that could be getting full in a server just like vmstat -z in FreeBSD.

P.S.: I know I can look at the logs, but if I have tons of lines it's a slow process.

Answer (score 2):

The details depend on the specific limit. In general, you'll get an error from a system call when it tries to exceed a limit. For instance, `open()` will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EMFILE` when if you can't open a file because of the openfile limit.

If you run out of heap memory, `malloc()` will return `NULL` to indicate that it can't allocate any more memory.

Since this is a programming site, I assumed you wanted to know how to do this in application programs. I have a feeling you're actually asking how to monitor the system in general for this, which is off-topic for SO -- sysadmin.com would be a better place.

Comment: yes, sorry @PePe, there's no easy answer short of installing a monitoring tool. That will take a lot of time to get right too, so you'll have to decide how important it is to your project and if you can afford to spend the time=is=money. Good luck.

Comment: I was thinking in the application side of things.

Comment: is there some documentation or site that talks about signals and return values and reasons for it ?

Comment: In broad terms, you are looking for the system library documentation.  Every system call is documented with input, output, and error conditions.  [`man 2 intro`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/intro); http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/